# Initializing complex constant in Constants interface

Tags: java

I'm being forced to use the common anti-pattern of a `public interface Constants` which many classes in this project implement.  Long story short, I need to have a `List` constant which is pre-populated with values.  Normally I would do this like so:

```
public static final List<String> MY_CONSTANT = new ArrayList<String>();
static {
    MY_CONSTANT.add("foo");
    MY_CONSTANT.add("bar");
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't use static initializers in an interface.  So after much frustration, I finally have my implementation as follows:

```
public static final List<String> MY_CONSTANT = new ArrayList<String>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1898990046107150596L;
    {
        add("foo");
        add("bar");
        // ...
    }
}
```

I hate the fact that I've made an anonymous extension like this and it makes me cringe.  Are there any better techniques I can use to accomplish this?  Changing the `Constants` file to a `class` instead of an `interface` isn't an option.  As I said, I'm just retouching a large, pre-existing code base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need constant of `java.util.List` type you can use static method [`java.util.Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

...

public static final List<String> MY_CONSTANT = asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

which creates immutable list instance with passed values.

In cases when more complex object needs to be initialised I like to use static methods which create my constant:

```
public static final SomeComplexObject constant = createMyConstant();

private static SomeComplexObject createMyConstant() {
    SomeComplexObject constant = new SomeComplexObject();
    constant.setProp1(...);
    constant.setProp2(...);
    ...
    return makeItSomehowImmutable(constant);
}
```

In your case you won't be able to declare `private static` method inside interface, so the only thing I find reasonable is to create separate utility class with static methods which create constants, declare your method there and reuse it just like with `java.util.Arrays.asList` method.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand your specific case entirely, but couldn't you just use enums for that purpose?

As in...

Simple version...

```
public enum MyConstants {
    FOO, BAR
}
// use method name() to get "FOO" or "BAR"...
```

Version with actual String values...

```
public enum MyConstants {
    FOO("foo"), BAR("bar");
    private String value; 
    MyConstants(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Certainly this could work, but I want to *reduce* complexity, not add more. +1